# Is this an adequate way of testing a shallow vs deep copy?

Tags: java, copy-constructor, deep-copy

Hi I am trying to devise a way of testing if a copy constructor is a deep or shallow copy. I have come up with the following. Would it work correctly? The output of the shallow copy is

```
Test1
Test1
```

Output of Shallow

```
Test1
```

Output of deep.

In my head this makes sense that its working correctly because in the deep copy nothing has been copied to the second instance.

```
public class DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor {

public String Stringtest ="";

public DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor(){
}

//Deep
public DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor(DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor other){
DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor test = new DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor();   
this.Stringtest = test.Stringtest;
}

//  //Shallow
//  public Testing(Testing other){  
//      this.Stringtest = other.Stringtest;
//  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor test1 = new DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor();
    test1.setStringtest("test1");
    System.out.println(test1.getStringtest());

    DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor test2 = new DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor(test1);
    System.out.println(test2.getStringtest());
}

public String getStringtest() {
    return Stringtest;
}

public void setStringtest(String stringtest) {
    Stringtest = stringtest;
}
}
```

Comment: I know they say names should be long in Java, but I think you're severely overdoing it to a point where the code is unreadable. Also, `Stringtest` definitely should not have capital S, it's not a type name. Also.. I've read it few times and still haven't understood your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays in here:

```
public DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor(DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor other){
DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor test = new DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor();   
this.Stringtest = test.Stringtest;
}
```

You probably wanted

```
public DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor(DeepAndShallowCopyConstructor other){
    this();
    this.Stringtest = other.Stringtest;
}
```

(though it's hard to guess your intention, the original code makes no sense to me.)

Then again, `Stringtest` should have small s, otherwise it's against the Java naming conventions, and the super-long names are making the code hard to read (even for you).